# Showing sub categories in a grid view

Tags: php, magento

I am very new to php and I wouldn't know much of OOP but I know little php, I have a store in which I want I to show subcategories when clicked on a link. Is there an extension or any other way to do this and where should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Are subcategories in a database. Considering your answer as yes, make the link point to something like

```
http://yoururl?cat=3 where 3 is the id of category.
```

Next run a database query to fetch the subcategories.You may use

```
$pid = (int)$_GET['cat'];
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE pid = '$pid'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
{
 while($f =mysql_fetch_array($query))
 echo $f['subcatname'];
}
```

Subcat = table for subcategories

pid  = column for parent id in subcat

subcatname = name of subcategories in subcat

Comment: But that is plain sql to run.what i want is when i click on the category page. the subcategories display on the page so each one can be clicked to see its listing

Answer (score 0):

You already have this in Magento. For enabling this, go to:
Catalog > Manage Categories > Click on subcategories individually > Display Settings tab > set Is Anchor to Yes

`Is Anchor` allows to make your categories/sub-categories filterable in Layered navigation.

Comment: i know but i want grid of images not a sidebar with categories

Comment: @RyanDiaz have you re-index the categories and checked?

Comment: The indexing is disabled and i am developing a theme back and forth. so i don't think its because of that. but what i want is when someone click on say "laptops" every brand comes with its logo and when someone click on "Apple" all apple laptop shows up. like that grid.

Comment: @RyanDiaz 1.) make sure ALL the cats and sub-cats are Is Anchor (set to yes). 2.) Re-index Category indexes, it can't be disabled, you need to re-index it.

Comment: how can i do a category reindex?

Comment: go to Admin > System > Index Management > Category Flat Data & Category Products

Comment: nope, its still showing in sidebar as links to filter. [link](http://genuinelyjanestudios.ammarworx.com/retail-store)